# Use Webpack HMR with a hoisted Lerna React Project

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, lerna, webpack-hmr

Is it possible to use Webpack Hot Module Replacement (HMR) with a **hoisted** Lerna React project?

This is because each Lerna React package (see below as an example) is built independently and when a webpack-dev-server is launched on the main project(p3 for instance), it can only see its own changes (I mean p3 changes only) and NOT its dependencies (p1 or p2) changes sitting in other packages of its monorepo

```
some_lerna_project
       /node_modules
       /packages
            /p1
              /src
              package.json
            /p2
              /src
              package.json
            /p3
              /src
              package.json
              webpack.confing.js
       lenra.json
```

If yes, would you please provide a sample config?

Answer (score 0):

You need these packages be part of transpiled files.

```js
// webpack.config.js

const path = require('path');

const PATH_DELIMITER = "[\\\\/]"; // match 2 antislashes or one slash

const safePath = (module) => module.split(/[\\\/]/g).join(PATH_DELIMITER);

const generateIncludes = (modules) => {
  return [
    new RegExp(`(${modules.map(safePath).join("|")})$`),
    new RegExp(
      `(${modules.map(safePath).join("|")})${PATH_DELIMITER}(?!.*node_modules)`
    ),
  ];
};

const transpileModules = ["@my-scope/p1", "@my-scope/p2"]; // using scoped packages

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: {
    app: "./src/index.js",
    print: "./src/print.js",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        include: generateIncludes(transpileModules),
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            // use your preferred babel config
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    symlinks: false, // Avoid Webpack to resolve transpiled modules path to their real path
  },
  output: {
    filename: "[name].bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  },
};
```

This code is based on [next-transpile-modules](https://github.com/martpie/next-transpile-modules/blob/master/src/next-transpile-modules.js) which enables Next.js projects to transpile mono-repo packages.